# VS2012 project cannot find output dll of Typescript project in bin folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I'm writing a game in TypeScript and just upgraded to TS 0.8.2 and now VS 2012 web express complains with an error like this:

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>    game -> C:\Users\me\pr\game.dll

I can confirm that this file exists on the file system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely file it cannot find is actually...

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.1.1\tsc

Which is probably now found under

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc

As they removed the version folder in 0.8.2.0 to save us from constantly updating this path in the project file!

The error message may be misleading - so check this path instead.

If you are using a 64 bit version of Windows, look in `Program Files (x86)` instead of the plain `Program Files`.

Comment: No problems. I only know the answer because it baffled me when I updated to 0.8.2 :)

Comment: I found it here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc

Comment: I will add that to my answer for 64 bit users.