# TypeScript compile error "Unknown file Extension"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript, tsc

I am getting build errors for multiple *.ts files. TypeScript compiler says

> Unknown extension for file: "<*filenameandpath*>.ts". Only .ts and .d.ts extensions are allowed.

These files build alright on save. Web Essentials never complains about anything and this is the only message I am getting in the output window. I am using VS 2012

Comment: Have you recently upgraded your version of TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get an error message like this when you upgrade from a pre 0.8.2.0 version of TypeScript. The error is in your project file, which is pointing at the wrong location for the compiler. For example, it is looking for:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.1.1\tsc
```

But the compiler is now located in:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc
```

You can [edit your project file to fix this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665718/vs2012-project-cannot-find-output-dll-of-typescript-project-in-bin-folder).

In your scenario, as you are using Web Essentials to compile on save and have all your checking at this point, you could switch off compilation on build entirely. Just remove that section from the project file.